# Python/Selenium Finding a specific class element, analyzing if it contains a specific span class, if it does, copy the link

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to create a script that loops through my inbox and find all div classes that contain "relative flex", if the div class contains a span class labelled "dn dib-1" then it copies and saves the following href link to my list and moves onto the next div.

Here is the html code:

```
   <div class="relative flex">
      <span class="dn dib-l" style="left: -16px;"</span>
      <a href="/conversations/269190401#newest_message" class="flex-auto mv0 f5 fw4 lh-copy light-gray truncate no-underline outline-none">hey how are you?</a>
```

Here is the code I have now:

```
link_list = []
sex_list = []
message = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="relative flex"]')
message_new = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="dn dib-l"]')
for item in message:
            link = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//a').get_attribute('href')
            if message_new in message:
                link_list.append(link)
```

Issue:
message, message_new all contain data when requested, however despite there being multiple messages with these classes, link variable only contains one element and link_list contains no elements. What changes do I need to make in my code in order for it to save all links within div classes that contain this span class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would restructure this code a bit to make it more efficient. To me, it sounds like you want to analyze all of the `div` elements that have class `relative flex`. Then, if the `div` contains a certain `span` element, you want to save the `href` tag of the following `a` item. Here's how I would write this:

```
# locate the span elements which exist under your desired div
spans_to_iterate = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'relative flex')]/span[contains(@class, 'dn dib-1')]")

link_list = []

# iterate span elements to save the href attribute of a element
for span in spans_to_iterate:

    # get the href element, where 'a' element is following sibling of span.
    link_text = span.find_element_by_xpath("following-sibling::a").get_attribute("href")
    link_list.append(link_text)
```

The idea behind this code is that we first retrieve the `span` elements that exist in your desired `div`. In your problem description, you mentioned you **only** wanted to save the link if the `div` and `span` elements contained specific class names. So, we query directly on the elements that you have mentioned, rather than find `div` first *then* find `span`.

Then, we iterate these `span` elements and use XPath's `following-sibling` notation to grab the `a` element that appears right after. We can get `get_attribute` to grab the `href` tag, and then append the link to the list.

Comment: Thank you, something else is wrong with the code but I understand your thought process and am going to apply it to solving the next step. With your current code I am getting the error message, "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/following-sibling::a"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)" I am just going to see if I could change the selector to something else. spans_to_iterate has the amount of values that it should but link_text/link_list contain nothing at the moment.

Comment: I had made a small typo in the XPath that I corrected just a minute ago. The correct syntax is `following-sibling::a`, not `/following-sibling::a` -- the leading `/` is what's causing the error I believe. I am basing this notation off this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59107473/python-selenium-finding-a-specific-class-element-analyzing-if-it-contains-a-spe/59107800#59107800

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
xpth = "//div[@class='relative flex' and /span[@class='dn dib-l']]//@href"
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(xpth)
```